# How to change boot order in grub2 to include bootable USB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I want to install Windows OS in an empty partition(dual-boot) using a bootable USB. However I can't seem to enter BIOS to change the boot order. Can I include the USB in the boot menu in GRUB2?

Comment: which hardware you are using? which laptop

Comment: Some systems seem to get locked up after multiple reboots. Other newer systems require specific changes in UEFI to allow USB boots. Often secure boot must be off & USB boot on.  If locked up full cold boot may be requried.  More info on cold boot reset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Comment: @PrashantChikhalkar Gateway NV55S

Answer (score 1):

> Can I include the USB in the boot menu in GRUB2?

Yes, it is possible. You have to edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file and add the following entry. So, open the `40_custom` file by:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

and add the following entry right after the last line.

```
menuentry "Windows-USB" {
        insmod chain
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd1'
        chainloader +1
}
```

Here. `hd1` is the USB containing bootable media. It can be different for you, so you have to get this number right or this will not work.

Save and close. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you restart your computer you'll see an entry named `Windows-USB`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the BIO Settings of your motherboard to set the order of boot devices.  Getting to the bios is unique for various hardware manufacturers.

When the computer is first powered on before it boots you will usually see the option for accessing the system's bios.  You would have to use that key (or key sequence).  Then follow the menu options.

Some common keys are:

DEL
F1
F2

For your particular computer, you may have to look at the manual to see your access key.

When installing Grub or modifying grub, you can specify which drive to install grub.  You can even choose to install grub on the USB pen drive.  However, you would have to modify the Motherboard's bios settings to actually make that the actual boot drive.