# How can I boot an Ubuntu 18 live USB from GRUB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 18 and Windows 10 installed in dual boot on my machine.

I now have to do some tuning on the disk partitions and wanted to do it with the gparted available directly on the Ubuntu live USB.

The problem is that I cannot manage to get the USB booting.
I unfortunately do not have access to the BIOS. Before I installed Windows, GRUB was directly booting the USB when I typed `exit` on the `grub>` command line which is how I could install it, but now when I do `exit` at the GRUB command line it boots directly to Windows 10.

How can I boot to the live USB from GRUB?

I tried the solution posted in [How to change boot order in grub2 to include bootable USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659451/how-to-change-boot-order-in-grub2-to-include-bootable-usb) and also mentioned [in this blog post](https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/07/29/how-to-boot-from-usb-with-grub2.html) and it did not work.

To give more information:
it is a UEFI boot

here are the information about the USB I get using
`lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid`

```
NAME        MOUNTPOINT                 LABEL         SIZE UUID
sdb                                                  7.2G 
└─sdb1      /media/rayan/UBUNTU 18_0   UBUNTU 18_0   7.2G 466D-342D
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Unfortunately, the boot process *before Ubuntu is run* is a feature of the BIOS / UEFI firmware, so you need to get that sorted first as those questions are off-topic here, but on-topic over at https://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Try configfile entry here, example uses your label, so make sure it has a label. https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive Or use  a chain type entry to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Assumes newer UEFI boot, not old BIOS boot.

Comment: @oldfred I think I tried this too. But did not try with a chain type. It is a UEFI boot btw. What would be the difference for a chain type entry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a GRUB2 menu entry for booting installed Ubuntu on a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @oldfred I found a solution by using [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive)

I had to modify it for my case like this:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 18 live" {
    search --set=root --label "UBUNTU 18_0"
    configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
}
```

and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

## Booting Full Install Flash Drive from Internal Grub

What works for me is to:

- Boot the computer from the internal drive.
- Plug in the Full install USB drive.
- Open Terminal and run:

  `sudo update grub`
- Next boot, Ubuntu from the USB drive, should appear as a grub option.

Note:
Running update-grub automatically adds the new menuentry(s) to 30_os-prober.
The menuentry(s) can be cut and pasted to 40_custom if desired.