# Can't load Windows 10 on fast boot setting

Tags: windows-10, grubrescue, syslinux

I updated to windows 10 a week ago. For class purposes, I needed to install ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 14.04, but then had to delete it for some reason. I deletrd the Linux partition feom windows 10(on fast boot setting ), then when I try to restart the windows it directly takes me to grub command line. As I read in other posts that it might be a problem with windows mbr being replaced, and for that I will have to usr a windows recovery disk. But the problem is, due to fast boot setting in windows 10, I am not able to get the startup optins, therefore I am not able to boot from my USB disk. Any suggestions would be life saving.

Comment: You can try a total cold boot and immediately press correct key to get into UEFI/BIOS. But if dual booting you need to have Windows fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 And best to restore correct boot loader before deleting another system that controls booting.

Comment: please forward your question here http://superuser.com/ or here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you will probably need to run `bootrec /RebuildBcd` then `bootrec /fixMbr` and finally `bootrec /fixboot` from the windows install disk

Comment: thanks. Was able to enter Startup options, and change the boot priorities. Will make sure to follow the suggestions you guys provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the F2 Key while powering on, this should take you to your bios where you can disable the fast boot and allow you to boot from your live usb. If F2 does not work why not try all the F keys one at a time to find your system default haha but in most cases it is F2

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Some devices (i.e. Sony Vaio have hardware keys to boot into BIOS, others use non-Fx-Keys - therefor it could make sense to check the related manual of your device how to get into BIOS.