# No wifi and can't enter BIOS, nor bootable with any kind of USB after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, wireless, nvidia, bios

Asus K401UB, Intel Core i5 6200U, nVidia 940M with Ubuntu 14.x.x was upgraded to 16.04.

The screen lit up:- Ubuntu at your service! Issues include:

- Wifi does not work
- Unable to select / enter BIOS
- Unable to select boot from USB

The computer just goes straight to the Ubuntu home screen after getting turned on!

Wifi doesn't work so I got the laptop connected using LAN cable

---

GREATE FINALE UPDATE:
I would like to say THANK YOU ALL for your patience and support. Finally I have had my laptop working. In fact the windows installation was so tricky as I never thought that setting up windows 7 on newer models would be impossible. Nevertheless, I survived thank to you guys and learned a lesson.
Thank you again!

Comment: I will be happy to help with the wireless. Let's start by identifying the device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with backslash. Edit your question to add the result and we'll proceed.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean by "wifi is just not there", you should elaborate. Regarding boot-repair you can download it and transfer it to your laptop with a usb stick from here:  https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair/+packages

Then run sudo dpkg -i name-of-package.deb

Comment: I did download the boot-repair***.tar.gz. Copied it to the ubuntu book, "terminal tar -zxvl" it - the thing extracted Now i got 3 brand new directories which I dont even know what to begin with and become slightly more clueless than how i was 30 seconds ago. I figured i should install it offline. But how this installation works without executable remains kind of mystery to me. I will try your command and see what will happen. Gracias!

Comment: If you had internet access I would suggest posting your hardware: `lshw | pastebinit`. You can also copy it to a file: `lshw > myHardwareConfiguration.txt`

Comment: Obviously I wasnt proud of it and thats why I came here asking for help/answer for the questions. But lets save your criticism for another day since i have kinda exhausted with the laptop already. And I say the bios problem is related to Ubuntu because right before I loaded the machine up with the flashy 16, there was nothing wrong with pressing F1/F2 accessing the BIOS.

Comment: The driver `iwlwifi` should work perfectly well. Make sure the wireless switch or key combination is not set to disable wireless: `rfkill list all` Is there any error when you load the module? `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`?

Comment: Since you have Ubuntu 16.04 (which is called Xenial), download this deb package: https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair/+files/boot-repair_4ppa38_all.deb and in the terminal inside the folder of the package, run sudo dpkg -i boot-repair_4ppa38_all.deb

Comment: I try rfkill list all and a list appeared, saying that phy0: wireless Lan hard blocked: yes" and there is in fact no wifi toggle button on my keyboard, so i guess it is about the driver. Meanwhile, the boot-repair_4ppa38_all.deb did run but was not seem ok because of  "dependency problem prevent configuration....". Actually i tried to install all the downloadable packages until it requires python-gi package, which made me kinda disappointed

Comment: The wireless "toggle" is probably a key combination, Fn+F12 or some such, that may be called Airplane Mode. Do you have that? Can you manipulate the combination and get `hard blocked:yes` to `no`? If so, I suspect your wireless will come to life!

Comment: I understand such concept. But as I read the manual as well as double-investigate my keyboard, such combination really doesn't exist, well technically. What is funnier is, in fact, 3 hours ago the wifi mysteriously worked for 20', up until the laptop finished its Software updating session automatically.

Comment: What is the make and model of the laptop, please?

Comment: The community is here to help and support questions.   The question was posed to understand the context better: no intention to irritate / belittle / embarrass.   If you do not have an application that requires 16, then you have more choices (good thing).   I find it exceptional that BIOS is now unavailable.  I would make it my first priority to regain this capability.  Suggest that you publish the make / model of the computer so that someone can help you reflash the BIOS and restore this capability.  Wishing you success

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the HDD and examining the BIOS boot sequence?  I would be interested in knowing if a boot w/o the HDD does restore BIOS access

Comment: The laptop im using is Asus k401ub, intel core i5 6200, with Nvidia 940m. and I just got it connected to internet using lan cable. Well had to walk 2 miles for the cable.

Comment: The laptop im using is Asus k401ub, intel core i5 6200, with Nvidia 940m. and I just got it connected to internet using lan cable. Well had to walk 2 miles for the cable.

Comment: If you can borrow a working Windows 10 drive (maybe the tech guy that installed Ubuntu-14, can help here), the two of you can attempt to restore BIOS access with utilities from: https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/784/0/2/lFj4wBlhcth111a8/45/   Before doing this, can you try booting without a HDD and post the BIOS / boot from USB availability?

Comment: I myself have a working windows 10 laptop. If its not about disassembling the laptops, I can do it.

Comment: In the past, I have had success transplanting a Win-10 drive from an HP  laptop to a HP desktop, so it may work.  I look forward to your next posting of the what you have tried and the observed results.  Though I do strongly suggest that you try to boot w/o the hard drive and see if you can gain access to the BIOS / boot from USB when the HDD is disconnected, before flashing the BIOS

Comment: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K401UB/0409_E10573_K401LB_K501LB_EM_V2_A.pdf  pp. 60 of the manual indicates F2 to enter the BIOS.  Have you successfully entered the BIOS before problems started?  Have you successfully booted from a USB device?  I am trying to imagine how Ubuntu could have altered (written) to the BIOS.  BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS: The BIOS file can be found here https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/784/0/2/lFj4wBlhcth111a8/8/     One hopes that it is user error and not a problem with the BIOS: unnecessary to flash the BIOS.  Maybe a youTube video of the startup?

Comment: it is like the egg or the chicken: if i want to enter Bios, i has to manage to boot with the usb. If i want to boot from USB, i have to change something in bios. Before this happen I had access to BIOS. but now the OS is just taking over everything. And besides, i managed to install Boot-repair, but I cant start it: Click the app, it shows up on the unity bar for a while then disappear.

Comment: Have you tried a "cold" boot to get into UEFI/BIOS? Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006  If you have Internet now working you can install Boot-Repair directly: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: My battery is non-removable, unfortunately. About the boot-repair, installed, but it refuses to work. see my update above.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have USB-boot capability and want to re-partition the drive:

1) On a windows laptop, [create a bootable rescueStick](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick#C.29_Recommended_USB_installation_method_from_Windows)

2) Boot the rescueStick and use the gParted application to re-partition drives

3) Reboot from Windows USB install disk and install windows

4) Go to fridge and reward yourself with your favorite beverage

If my memory is correct, You should not have to perform steps 1) and 2) because a Windows install stick should allow you to repartition the disk.  If my memory is incorrect, then the sure way to re-partition is with the rescueStick.

If your intent is to have a dualboot machine, then [this article indicates that Windows should be installed first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers to the same question. Though I expect that your other post is going to be deleted by the mods because it's asking for more information instead of providing an answer.