# Have the developers of Ubuntu developed code to access the BIOS in the Toshiba Satellite P875-S7200 laptop?

Tags: boot, 16.04, bios, toshiba-satellite

I am in the process of replacing Windows 7 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but have not found a way to access the BIOS in my system. Unlike every machine I have owned in the past, primarily DELL desktops and laptops, Toshiba linked BIOS access to Windows 7.

In Windows, I must navigate from the Start to an application that will permit me to alter BIOS... there are no access keys on bootup; a very annoying feature of this particular product. While I have set the BIOS to boot up with USB first, I may wish change that configuration for security reasons in the future or at least password protect the boot process.

I noticed there is no intelligent discourse on this very important issue for Toshiba owners at this time... hence the question.

Comment: Sounds like you should give Toshiba a piece of your mind. I've been buying Toshiba for many years but I'll stop now.

Comment: So this really is UEFI not BIOS? And most UEFI have a fast boot setting which works to speed boot, if no system changes are made but does not give time to press keys to get into UEFI. Turn off fast boot in UEFI.  Does this entry work in grub menu? http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8 or cold boot http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8

Comment: @oldfred Yes, its UEFI/CSM. Now that I re-read OP's question, OP simply needs to turn off fastboot. Holding Fn+f2 (or just F2) at boot should work.

Comment: There must be a way. They'd be stupid to not include a way to do it without a Windows OS.

Comment: Not that I can find. I went to Toshiba and their answer was to access the app inside Windows 7...