# Booting to Gnu Grub 2 after installing Ubuntu studio

Tags: grub2, uefi

I can't boot into windows or Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu on a live USB but I am unable to boot from that either. Not sure what I should do.

I also cannot access bios any more.

[image: picture of issue]

Comment: You sure link is correct?

Comment: Are you consistently booting in UEFI or BIOS. All installs must be same. And how you boot flash drive is how it installs UEFI or BIOS, which may not be default in UEFI/BIOS? Can you cold boot to get back into UEFI? http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8