# Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on Asus H170 Pro Gaming

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, asus, windows-10

this question is specific for Asus H170. so please dont rush and mark it duplicate.

I am trying to follow the [general guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) of disabling the secure boot. But in the Asus H170 UEFI I can't find such option.

I want dual boot because I play games on Windows and do Machine/Deep Learning on Ubuntu. GTX 1080 | i5 6500.

I have spent almost a day but still confused. If anyone has done in Asus H170/Z170 please help me.

My bios looks like this. This guy confused me a lot.

https://www.technorms.com/45538/disa...i-bios-utility

Comment: In your BIOS, go to the `BOOT` tab.  Scroll down to `CSM`, ensure `Launch CSM` is Enabled.  Scroll back down the `BOOT` tab to `Secure Boot`, change the `OS Type` to "Other OS".  Save and reboot/exit.

Comment: The advice above will make the factory installed Windows unbootable. You really need to follow the instructions you linked.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I just did follow those instructions. restarted pressed F8 at the start - selected the USB as boot device it still loads windows. used Rufus - GAT Partition - FAT32 bootable usb device. not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/891248/ubuntu-16-04-how-can-i-disable-secure-boot/891295#891295) for some pointers on launching the firmware's setup utility, and [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) for several illustrated examples of disabling Secure Boot. Unfortunately, there's no standardization on this matter; it even varies from one model to another from the samer manufacturer. Thus, in the end you may need to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I somehow got it to boot. I have created a 50 gb partition for ubuntu. C drive has windows. D drives has all games, movies and stuff. G drive  50 gb is for ubuntu. how should isplit this into home,root and swap ?