# How do I disable secure boot in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Windows 10 Microsoft store version)?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, lts, secure-boot

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from the Microsoft store on my Windows 10 machine and trying to install CUDA on it. Along the installation process I get the following error:

`Executing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.33.01.run --ui=none --no-questions --accept-license --disable-nouveau --no-cc-version-check --install-libglvnd 2>&1`

And after some internet browsing I find that the solution is to  disable secure boot on my Ubuntu 18.04. My problem is that I can't find how to disable secure boot specifically for the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS **app** on my Windows 10 machine—all the solutions are for Ubuntu as an OS that loads once one restarts their computer.

All help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You should be using Windows drivers for your Windows system. Ubuntu under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) does not have direct control of the hardware. Windows retains that control.

Comment: Secure Boot is controlled by UEFI. But the Microsoft Ubuntu install does not support a GUI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/993225/whats-the-easiest-way-to-run-gui-apps-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-as-of-2018 &  https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 - how can I disable Secure Boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891248/ubuntu-16-04-how-can-i-disable-secure-boot)