# Fan control doesn't work

Tags: fancontrol

My laptop fan doesn't work now.

I want to control it. The `sensors` command doesn't show the fan speed.

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +41.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +45.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

    ahmet@ahmet:~$ sensors-detect
You need to be root to run this script.
ahmet@ahmet:~$ sudo sensors-detect
[sudo] password for ahmet: 
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: LENOVO 20236 [Lenovo G500] (laptop)
# Board: LENOVO INVALID
# Kernel: 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz (6/58/9)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes         
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.                                                                                                                        
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no):
```

Comment: Many laptops don't show fan speed or allow to control it from OS. You need to repair your laptop.

Comment: what steps have you taken?  Have you run `sensors-detect`?

Comment: @rtaft I added the output.

Answer (score 1):

This is your (first) issue: `Operation not permitted`.  This is likely because Secure Boot is enabled.  Try follwing the steps here to disable it. 
 [Ubuntu 16.04 - how can I disable Secure Boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891248/ubuntu-16-04-how-can-i-disable-secure-boot)

Comment: In addition to that, you may need to also add

`acpi_enforce_resources=lax` in your grub options.