# New user having installed ubuntu 18+, but fan is going crazy

Tags: laptop, asus, fan

I have been extremely patient for a few weeks now, but I gave up on windows and installed Ubuntu thinking it was a software issue. It looks it is.

ASUS laptop, 8Gb ram, 64 bit,... I cleaned the fan.

So, I went on terminal and used the sensor program and this is what it came up with:

```
**Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
(driver `coretemp')
```

Everything else ran negative
except (but I don't know what this is)

```
Client found at address 0x18
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Post the details of the Super IO section from `sensors-detect`.  Does everything come back 'no' in that?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! All is negative. Here is a glimpse: Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Comment: I thought I could install sensor monitor to help, but it shows nothing, but maybe I need to make it work in terminal.

Comment: To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK How do I do that, if I need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The scan is unable to run properly and you are receiving the error "Operation not permitted".  This is most likely caused by secure boot being enabled.  [Ubuntu 16.04 - how can I disable Secure Boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891248/ubuntu-16-04-how-can-i-disable-secure-boot)

Comment: hi! THANKS for helping. I am able to access my bios.

Comment: In the boot section, it shows that secure bot is active and enabled. you want me to disable it? Active? System mode is user. There is a key management tab just below that. Sorry, but I know next to nothing about this. thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: Just read this: windowslatest.com/2019/09/04/…. Now that is exactly what happened to me. Sadly I cannot fix windows because i kicked it out of the ... door already! lol

Comment: The link I posted was instructions for Ubuntu.