# Can't enter UEFI/Bios, Ubuntu loading directly

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've made a dual boot in a Dell Optiplex 7020 with a existing Windows 10. Now Ubuntu is booting directly, grub doesn't seems to load (or if it loads it doesn't show nothing in the menu) and I can't access BIOS/UEFI. Dell logo doesn't appear anymore and using the keys that I used before doesn't do nothing. Also, I can't boot from a USB stick as I can't do anything with BIOS/UEFI. I have no clue what can be done...

Comment: If UEFI you can press Escape key or if BIOS press and hold shift key to get into grub menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8 If you have fwsetup as last entry in grub menu you can use that. Otherwise try cold boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8 If at grub menu.UEFI fast boot fwsetup is to get into UEFI.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8

Comment: You may be able to access the firmware setup utility by typing `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`. Beyond that, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

On start up press f8. Grub will appear then. You can choose system settings or advanced setting (I forget  the menu name). You will enter uefi bios from there.

Comment: This solution worked best for me, even if I can't enter uefi or bios through terminal, I can do it the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start grub with command `grub` in a terminal. This allows you to see what grub does and how it starts up all the systems.

Then run `root (hd  -then hit the <Tab> key to auto-complete.` once you are logged into grub. This will show you a number of disk options, and once you select the disk you want, with a command looking like this `grub> root (hd0,` you should be able to see all the partitions of the harddisk selected.

For a list of all commands look here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-grub-commands.html and use what is required to modify what you startup.