# Dual boot after ubuntu install not working - NO EFI and different hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Edit: I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 in a **different** hard drive than Windows, but grub is not loading after install.

I found a lot of topics relating windows 10 in EFI mode and Ubuntu, but my windows 10 is installed in legacy mode. Checking windows 10 disk management I don't have an EFI partition, so that confirms that I'm in legacy mode (double checked in BIOS and in Windows info).

I followed [this guide on tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) to install Ubuntu.

I adapted the tutorial to install Ubuntu in a different hard drive. I installed Ubuntu in `/dev/sdb2` and 3 (the partitions that I created: root and home) and grub was installed in `/dev/sdb`.

Windows 10 is installed in `/dev/sda1`, and windows boot loader is installed in `/dev/sda`.

After Ubuntu is finished and I reboot, grub is never loaded. I even tried changing boot order BIOS order to first look into Ubuntu HDD, but nothing happens and windows is loaded.

Any clues on what might be happening?

Edit2: I'm running a desktop with an asrock mobo, 1 ssd and 1 hdd. Windows is installed in a M.2 ssd and Ubuntu is installed in the hdd

Comment: If you installed in legacy mode in a GPT drive you also a need a small non-formated partition called `bios_grub` or something like that.

Comment: May need to see if grub did install correctly to sdb. Easiest with Summary Report from Boot-Repair which also gives lots of other info. some do not get report into pastebin site, which it should do if you ok it, but if it does not post, then manually copy it to a pastebin site. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Answer (score -1):

BIOS boots from the first HDD it finds with a bootloader in the MBR or flagged boot partition.
Since you have windows installed on sda, BIOS will boot from sda.
Thus, grub needs to be installed on sda.
I does not matter where ubuntu is installed. Grub will find it and make the appropriate entry.
Another option is to swap the drive cables, so ubuntu is sda and windows is sdb.

Comment: Some BIOS does not require booting from sda. In his case, he can actually change his boot order.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy - I have never seen a BIOS that lets you select which internal drive to boot from. It will boot the first bootable drive it finds

Comment: It's just you. My 10-year-old computer supports booting up from another internal drive.

Comment: @Cynplytholowazy -- yours is a rarity

Comment: @ravery https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606683

this guy has ubuntu installed in sdb. Remember that I have OS installed in different HDD

Comment: @AugustoDuflothNetto -- but you have a bootloader on sda. he does not. so for him sdb is the first bootable internal HDD. this is not the case for you. it doesn't matter where ubuntu is installed, grub needs to be on the first bootable drive.

Comment: @ravery Can you **[edit]** this to include the fuller explanation in the answer?

Comment: @ravery maybe I wasn't clear. In Bios I am booting first grub, but grub never loads and I'm taken to windows. If I remove windows from the boot sequence and keep only sdb in the boot sequence , then grub never loads and I'm taken straight to bios

Comment: Legacy boot does not boot by OS. that is for EFI boot, which you are not doing.