# No boot after update, no access to BIOS

Tags: 14.04, boot, updates

First of all, happy new year to all.

I seem to have a major issue with the updates of Ubuntu 14.04 installed today (10 Jan 2018). It worked flawlessly before restart, but now nothing happens.

Usually, my computer takes only a few seconds to boot and takes me straight to the login screen. Here, I have nothing on screen and no sound to tell me that the login screen has been reached, so I assume it isn't booting. I have attempted to use a Lubuntu LiveUSB to prompt an alternate boot, but it doesn't notice it, and I cannot access the BIOS (I have tried a variety of keys). I never have been able to access the BIOS on initial boot, I can only do that when restarting my computer from a successful first boot, so some kind of fast track boot is in place.

My machine is a Shuttle XPC, and Ubuntu 14.04 is the only OS installed on it.

I think what I need before anything else is a way to get around this fast boot.

Sorry if this has appeared on here before, and I'd appreciate the help if you can provide some. Cheers, Matthew

Comment: If UEFI do you have this grub menu item? `menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
 fwsetup`  Otherwise you can try total cold boot Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Comment: You can consult Shuttle site for BIOS-key, but usually it is `Del` or `Esc`.

Comment: Thank you both, I'm back on. oldfred, your link contained the words "cold boot", and searching a bit, I found how to do that. I was very scared I'd have to dismantle something. I've disabled Fast Boot for the future. I don't mind losing some start-up time if it means I can address issues in events like these... N0rbert, thank you for the link. It was the 4.4.0-108 I had installed. I had the extra problem of needing a cold boot. Thank you both again, issue solved!