# Ubuntu Dual Boot uninstallation problem

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, bios, toshiba-satellite

I am trying to uninstall Ubuntu from my dual boot Windows 10 *Toshiba Satellite L50*.

I followed several tutorials that told me to remove the Ubuntu partitions and  then boot from a Windows repair USB device. Problem is that I cannot access the BIOS. I tried <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F8</kbd>,<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>INS</kbd>. It always go to `grub` and since it cannot find the Ubuntu partition, it enters *rescue mode*.

I think that the computer was not completely shut down so BIOS is not possible. However, now I cannot boot again to shut down properly.

Do you know how to hard reboot the computer so I can access the BIOS ?

Comment: You change boot to default Windows before removing Ubuntu as part of grub is in UEFI or BIOS/MBR and part in the partition. If UEFI you need to get into UEFI to change boot order. If fast start up is on, then you need "cold" boot. Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 My desktop locked up hard with multiple tries to a USB full install. I tried all the suggestions and only disconnecting boot drive worked.

Comment: Thank you, I think it was a fast startup problem. As you suggested, I removed the battery and then I was able to access the BIOS. After doing boot repair with the USB device, my computer boots on windows

Comment: @oldfred Looks like you need to provide an answer instead of the two low-quality ones this now attracted...

Comment: Answer was in link, so really a duplicated. OP can give say that post was useful.

Answer (score 1):

It was a fast startup problem. As @oldfred suggested, removing the battery solved the problem

Comment: It's not required, though nice of you to ask the person that helped you to provide an answer first before you answer yourself.  That way he can recoopu some rep for the time he spent in helping you...  **0:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows if you can, I think type in this command in Advanced Startup, bootsect /nt60 c: /fixmbr and then delete the Ubuntu partition, and then GRUB And Ubuntu will be uninstalled...

Comment: This will not remove GRUB.