# Can't get to BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, bios

I've got both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Previously I was able to switch between then accessing BIOS and choosing between Legacy mode boot and UEFI.

I've made several updates for Windows 10 and couldn't get to BIOS pressing `Enter`. Then I've found some UEFI settings in Windows 10 and was able to switch to a Legacy mode to get to Ubuntu: I was faced with `grub-rescue`, set prefix, boot and etc and was able to get to Ubuntu.

But now I can't get to BIOS pressing `Enter` as before: it is simply ignored. F1, F2, F12 - all don't work. I've tried `update-grub`, then `grub-install` - the later fails with `error: will not proceed with blocklists.` (--force - the same behavior). I've also tried using `boot-repair` but I'm getting an error saying I should use UEFI mode. Obviously, I can't use it as I can't enter BIOS.

How do I get to BIOS?

**UPDATE** The question identified as having a similar issue doesn't help me. First of all, I'm not in EFI mode. Then, I don't have an opportunity to disassemble my laptop unplugging its hardware. I would like to reset or simply get to the laptop firmware somehow. One of the answers proposes to use `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` but that doesn't work because I'm not in EFI.

Comment: @starkus can't try the first one but the second approach seems to be interesting. Could you please advise how to do it?

Comment: @starkus interesting, thank you. but it will help me to switch to Windows only, right? or is there a way to repair BIOS itself?

Comment: @starkus that is very helpful, thank you! I will certainly try it. sounds like a solution

Comment: Systems should be in same boot mode. Since Windows is UEFI,  install the UEFI version of grub to convert your Ubuntu install to UEFI. You can use Boot-Repair. Since Windows is UEFI, you have gpt partitioning. So if you really want Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode, you must have a 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag. Grub does not like blocklist install which it uses (maybe) when you do not have bios_grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Make sure fast boot is off in UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006

Comment: From your description Windows is in UEFI ode and Ubuntu is in BIOS mode: reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode or get a manufacturer EFI/BIOS upgrade

Comment: The easiest way for entering bios. Remove your bios cell and then start your system. system through time/date error, you just press f1. you got your destination bro! ;)

NOTE: remove battery or light plugs before removing bios cell.