# can't enter bios how can i solve?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, bios

I deleted my Ubuntu partition from my Windows 10 drive, but now when I power on the PC, Windows does not start. All I see is "error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>_", so I thought to change the boot order. However, I can't enter the BIOS screen. Before, I was able to change the boot order by pressing F12, but now if I press it, it does nothing. I can't even enter into the bios with F2 when it says "press F2 to enter bios" and "F12 boot options". I can't see those options anymore.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Windows has fast start up, but UEFI has fast boot. Fast boot assumes you have made no system changes and jumps immediately to booting. That often does not give time to press a key to get into UEFI. Often, just a full cold boot, not warm reboot works. If laptop also remove battery and hold power switch for 10 sec or so, to all power used. If not you may have to remove coin battery on motherboard. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8

Comment: Sometimes holding down f2 after power-up might work, or typing it rapidly.  Without the delay, it can be tricky, but usually possible.

Comment: Insert your Windows DVD and try to repair disk/boot repair.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have changed the hard disk with another one with windows on it then i get in the bios by keeping pressed shift and pressing one time the shutdown button at the same time , and then i was able to get in bios.