# Old noob corrupted his dual boot, (bios legacy boot?). Any suggestions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have an old Aspire E1-470P which I had upgraded through Win10. It was getting bogged down so I months ago set up a dual boot in Ubuntu 18.04 with limited disk space partition. I may have deleted my OEM partition at this point. This all went well and I really got to like Ubuntu.

I decided to expand my partition. I made sure I had my last macrium backup and rescue on a USB drive, created a Ubuntu 18.04 boot thumb drive, and rebooted. I kept on coming right back to the dual boot menu. So I went into the setup for bios and tried alternate boot options, placing the USB drive at the top of the boot order but I continued to get the dual boot window. Finally (Here is where I blew up Akron) I toggled the boot mode and the secure boot. I cannot be sure what position I left them in, but I am pretty sure toggling the secure boot to legacy hosed the boot options.

When I tried to boot, I got the pink set up options screen followed by the black screen (Link training failed at link rate...).  I tried to boot from my 2TB drive containing Macrium and the startup ISO, but it does not recognize it.  I researched and found the "nomodeset" solution.  After several tries I managed to get into the 18.04 trial OS.

So, now I am running the Trial 18.04 OS, but I would very much like to get back to my dual boot. I can see my folders in the "other locations" and access them, but I would like very much to return to my previous install.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I recognize that this is as much an aspire Boot / BIOS question as a Ubuntu question, but I would be willing to live with my previous install of Ubuntu if I could get back to it. I just don't know how to fix my boot options.

I should add that the <kbd>F2</kbd> at startup screen does nothing, and that booting without the Ubuntu thumb drive produces an “Operating System Not Found”

Comment: Systems now offer both UEFI & legacy/BIOS. But you have to install both systems in same boot mode and make sure not to change boot modes. It sounds like you need to go into UEFI and change boot mode to turn Secure boot off, but keep UEFI boot on. Be sure to boot in UEFI mode: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not post full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I receive the following error.    The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode

Comment: Hi oldfred. I think the problem is that I cannot boot into uefi. I think I changed uefi to legacy BIOS and (if i understand) i cannot access it. When I try to hit f2 from the acer startup screen I get a beep and it goes straight to the Ubuntu setup screen (keyboard and silhouette icon).  I tried the Boot-Repair and it is telling me I need to boot in UEFI mode...but I suspect if I was I could get back to  UEFI I would see my original boot options

Comment: I thought I had this fixed bu installing a new version of Ubuntu and simply moving documents and files.   but now when I boot with my HDMI monitor attached I get a black and white boot option screen and after that a illegible white screen with vertical black lines.  Boot looks ok when I boot without the monitor.

Comment: New UEFI has fast boot which assumes no system changes and immediately boots. Normally no time to press any keys. But cold boot or full power down, if laptop also remove battery. Pust power button to drain all power. Then boot & press f2 or correct key to get into UEFI/BIOS. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8 Also if any model Acer & UEFI you will need to set "trust" & update UEFI from Acer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947

Comment: In the end, I had to remove battery, open the laptop,, remove the cmos battery and HDD, replace CMOS battery, attempt boot ("Operating System not found"), reinstall HDD, reboot and voila, back to UEFI boot. From there I was able to boot back into my original Ubuntu install.  Finally I used the windows boot utility to boot into Ubuntu Live disk, deleted unused partitions and everything is working fine.