# How to get to the GRUB menu in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox

How do I break into the GRUB menu when booting a single-boot Ubuntu 19.04 system? I've tried all of the key combinations I can find online (Esc, Shift, Space, c) and nothing keeps the system from booting Ubuntu right away.

My deeper issue is that I upgraded an 18.04 system to 19.04, and everything went fine, but when I did the final reboot, the system got stuck with a purple screen after the usual Ubuntu logo with the progress dots under it -- no GDM, and no apparent way to log in. Many suggested workarounds involve tweaking GRUB parameters, which would be great, if only I could get to GRUB.

This is a VirtualBox VM, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hold down the Shift key. The *right-side* Shift key. I found lots of references about holding down Shift, but only after considerable digging did I find one that says it needs to be *right* Shift.

Comment: Shift key is for BIOS boot systems. With UEFI, it is escape key right after UEFI/BIOS screen. But if UEFI fast boot is on, you may not have time to press any keys & need to do a cold boot, not a warm reboot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006