# How can I boot from a Xubuntu LiveUSB? My Desktop is broken

Tags: boot, xubuntu, .desktop

Whenever I turn on my computer it opens to a terminal and I have to log in there and run `startx` to get to my Xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Desktop. I have no idea how to get back the normal login screen, when I press the arrow key it just cycles through the terminals and never goes back to the login screen.

The problem is I don't know how to make Xubuntu boot from the installation media and not boot into Xubuntu on the internal drive.

Comment: You do not boot flash drive from within Xubuntu, but from BIOS or UEFI. You press BIOS/UEFI boot key before grub even starts. You may need to check system manual, but many use f10 or f12 as UEFI or BIOS boot key to select boot. If UEFI and you have fast boot on in UEFI, you may not have time to press any key. Then you may need a "cold" boot or full power shutdown, so UEFI does scan system for changes & gives you a couple of seconds to press a key. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-wi ndows-8

Comment: Ohhhh, this makes more sense, I'll try this out.

Comment: Alright so I don't seem to be able to access the UEFI

Comment: When I boot and press f12, nothing happens the xubuntu continues to load, only now it displays all the processess its doing on screen as it boots.

Comment: Note the keys are machine specific; I have machines that use F9, machines that ignore any Fn key (it has it's own blue key that pulls up the menu)... ie. it's machine specific; however it's also a hardware issue & not a Ubuntu/Xubuntu issue thus off-topic here.  (*If you installed Ubuntu server; no gui is expected; and gui can be disabled by default*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: @Path Please click [edit] and add the make and model of your PC to the question so we can search and find what the key is to access Boot Options. Please get the model number from the sticker which also has the serial number on it, because 'model names' on the lid, bezel, top case, or keyboard surround are often not the true model name. Please don't use Add Comment to reply; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)