# Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot concern and issue

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just bought and installed an SSD and installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
I noticed that in the storage settings of Windows 10, it shows the entire capacity of my SSD rather than just the Windows 10 partition. On top of that the System Files category of the storage usage summary is counting all of the storage space in the partitions for Ubuntu.

I'm not sure if this will cause any issues, but it wasn't like this in my previous Windows 10 install on my old HDD.

I'm also having a bit of issue with grub not showing up on boot. Maybe I've got some partition problems or something?

Here's an image.

[image: incorrect storage]

Boot-repair summary info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GR6Mp2GqRp/

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I've got the ppa version of boot repair. I'll edit my post with the boo-info summary.

Comment: Looks normal. You do have a copy of Windows BIOS boot loader in MBR, but that should not be ever used. Just do not try to boot in CSM(BIOS)  boot mode as it will fail. You show Linux partitions. Windows may be counting that as the free space as Windows does not see or not correctly see Linux partitions. BIOS mode Windows would just forget to include Linux partitions in partition table on major updates.Recent seen a couple of users with similar issue with gpt. 
`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt`

Comment: I tried the command you provided and had no change it seems. 
Is there any more info you'd like me to provide?
Both issues are a bit annoying but as far I know they aren't causing too much problems for me yet at least.

Comment: Is Fast Boot on in UEFI settings? Is fast start up off in Windows settings. Grub should normally show since more than one system to choose from. Do not know Windows issues.

Comment: Fast startup was on but I have now disabled it. I restarted the computer and set the boot order so Ubuntu would try to boot before Windows. Grub is still not showing up. There is a period of time where the screen is just black and then a horizontal line flashes just briefly before the Ubuntu boot splash screen displays.

Comment: If you press escape right after UEFI/BIOS screen, do you get grub menu? I also like to see boot progress and supposed this speeds boot somewhat by changing grub, test first as you boot before editing /etc/default/grub: changed from quiet splash to noplymouth, will see boot process rather than Ubuntu logo

Comment: Sorry for responding so slowly. If I press escape while booting to Ubuntu I get some sort of diagnostics screen. Could you rephrase the rest of your comment because I don't understand you mean.

Comment: You do not get grub menu, or is it somehow booting the recovery mode and gives a menu of repair options? Replace quiet splash on linux line with noplymouth. Screen shot of where quiet splash is: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters You have to get to grub menu with escape if UEFI boot or shift key if BIOS boot.

Comment: I'm sorry about not responding sooner. I was focusing on my classes.
I have done what you have said and I get no grub menu still. However, I enabled the grub init beep and I think grub does start as my computer beeped. It seems that the UI does not show on screen but grub is actually there. 

I pressed the down key and waited until after the default timeout time and nothing happened. Then I pressed the up key and enter and ubuntu immediately started to boot! 
So what do you think is causing the UI to not show up?

Comment: Do you have nVidia? Possible video issue. And then you need to get grub menu & add nomodeset. If booting in UEFI Mode, escape key right after UEFI/BIOS screen will show grub menu. If booting in BIOS mode shift key is used. You also need fast boot off in UEFI, or you may not have time to press any key. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006

Comment: Here's a bit more info I've got: Secure boot is disabled, windows is in uefi mode, ubuntu seems to be in uefi mode, bios or whatever is in uefi mode. Like I said above, Grub seems to actually load without UI. Pressing ESC key repeatedly brings me this screen https://imgur.com/z6kiIAF .

Comment: Yes I have nvidia. I'll try nomodeset now.

Comment: You may need firmware updates, both UEFI & SSD. The UEFI screen should be from f2 or delete key. Some with issues, switch to use Intel video until they get everything working, then add nVidia driver & change connection back to the nVidia port.

Comment: Alright, nomodeset made no change. Next I tried using novueau drivers and no change. Then I used the command prime-select Intel and no change. I to the went uefi screen and set graphics mode to Intel only but still no grub ui.

Comment: Are you booting and not getting grub screen to choose what to boot? Then I would not be changing video modes. I think I see more issues where users do not want grub menu which is opposite issue. Note that 19.04 will reach EoL in Jan 2020.

Comment: I seem to be getting the functioning grub menu but no display, just blank screen. I'm going to upgrade to 19.10 or go back to 18.04 soon. I just hope that this issue doesn't persist after that or I don't do something to cause it again.

Comment: One time I changed grub font colors. Ended up with white font on white background. That did not work so well.

Comment: Just checked if that was it. Nothing still though. This is pretty weird.
For a little while sudo apt upgrade would give me a dpkg error. Something about grub stuff missing or not fully installed. I got that to go away but still have this problem.

Comment: It may be best then just to do a full reinstall of grub. That resets everything back to defaults. If you changed anything save a backup of that, but do not necessarily restore it as that may have been issue. You can use Boot-Repair or if in your system uninstall & reinstall grub. Note if you reboot when uninstalled, it will not reboot. Full grub uninstall/reinstall
`sudo apt purge grub-efi-amd64` &
`sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64`

Comment: I went and tried rEFInd to see if that had any issue too. It worked so I guess my grub install was indeed messed up. I suppose if I have any issues with rEFInd I'll go ahead and reinstall grub like you suggested.

Comment: I have used rEFInd for emergency boot and have it on an old too small now for anything else flash drive. I has UEFI/grub issues and rEFInd was the only thing that booted. Grub is both a boot menu & boot loader, rEFInd is just the boot menu. Some also use SuperGrub for emergency boot. Have not recently used it, but did back in BIOS days. SuperGrub now also works with UEFI.