# l can't enter BIOS because Ubuntu loads too fast

Tags: boot, bios

I try `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and try to change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=5` but when I save, I get this:

```
** (gedit:5998): WARNING **: 20:18:19.296: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

Then I try to reboot my laptop and again, Ubuntu loads too fast for me to enter BIOS.

Comment: Do you use EFI-Boot?

Comment: Try `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` then run `sudo update-grub`. Best to never use 0, I use 3 just so I have enough time if quick to enter grub menu. You can also get to BIOS if you turn off fast boot in UEFI so you have time to press the key to get into UEFI/BIOS. Beside f2 or whatever key is correct, and grub menu entry to get into UEFI, this also should work. `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` Also total cold boot, or full power shutdown & drain power. If laptop remove battery to drain all power. Then UEFI does not do fast boot, but normal boot.

Comment: Some laptops(eg. my Lenovo Ideapad) wont load the BIOS if you  `restart` it. Only loads with the relevant key is pressed during boot after a complete poweroff(via the shutdown command ).

Answer (score 34):

The warning message you got is not important. You can ignore that one.

Your problem will not be solved, when grub takes longer to choose. You first start with your BIOS layer, then you will get to grub and grub loads the Linux-kernel and hence Ubuntu. When you have reached grub, there is no way back into the BIOS Setup.

But in GNU/Linux you can reboot directly into the BIOS Setup, by the following command:

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

---

I found the command on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/519718/linux-on-uefi-how-to-reboot-to-the-uefi-setup-screen-like-windows-8-can).

Comment: The grub timeout *does* matter if it's an EFI system and the grub menu has a "System Setup" option (or if you know the grub command for it, which is `fwsetup`).

Comment: Does it work for classical BIOS, not UEFI?

Comment: @hobbs: However, the OP is very explicit in that they want to enter the *BIOS*, not the EFI. They use the term "BIOS" twice in the question, and tagged the question with [tag:bios], whereas they use the term "EFI" or "UEFI" zero times, and haven't applied an EFI or UEFI related tags to the question, so we can safely assume that the question is about BIOS, not EFI.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's a very optimistic view. Not wanting to underestimate the OP, but the number of people that haven't noticed that newer versions of computers don't come with BIOS anymore is staggering.

Comment: Every PC I've used has had a way to disable EFI, which I've always used. Even ones made in the last few years.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I can assure you that is not the case anymore. Some UEFI/EFI computers have BIOS emulation and more and more don't even have that these days.

Comment: Microsoft required all vendor to use UEFI with gpt partitioning when Windows  8 was released in 2012. Many vendors still call it BIOS as do most users that are not familiar with newer UEFI. Currently there is  CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, but Intel is now promoting finally doing away with CSM in future systems. Often issue of getting into UEFI/BIOS is fast boot setting in UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8