# Ubuntu boot to black screen, cannot access grub and bios with anu keys

Tags: 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with usb. I can access bios at that time. While after installation, my computer boot to black screen with mouse moveable and can go to tty by use ctrl + alt +F2 so my keyboard also works. I have searched lots of solutions but I just cannot go to grub or bios with pressing any key during booting, F1, F2, to F12, Shift, Esc and Del, tapping or holding. All keys I tried, no one can let me get to GRUB or BIOS. I can only go to tty, but nothing I can do to fix my computer. HELP!

Comment: Do you have fast boot on in UEFI, which is different setting than fast start up in Windows. Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8
If UEFI install: `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware` or
`sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`

Comment: @oldfred Thank you very much! Even I still have no idea about what happened on my computer. After a real cool boot, unplug it for whole night, now it works!