# How to skip the grub-bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue

I'm having a problem with my microsoft surface. I wanted to reinstall Arch (because it was very slow) so I removed the grub folder in the boot partition (I don't know the reason anymore why I did that...). Somehow I had a problem with `openssl` so I just my laptop (I know, that's stupid but I was too lazy to look after the reason) in order to try the installation again. But I when I'm booting my laptop, it always starts the grub-rescue command line... I tried to get into the UEFI before the grub-rescue pops up but it looks like, that my keyboard is activated when grub pops up, so I can't get into the UEFI-Settings and change the boot order. I've also tried to install a linux system on my USB to mount it with the grub-rescue cmd but it can't detect it with `ls`. My last idea is skipping the grub-rescue cmd to boot into windows. Do you have an idea how I can achieve this or any other ideas?

Comment: You do not remove any parts of grub until you reconfigure to boot something else. You probably have UEFI fast boot on, which then gives no time to press any keys. You can try cold boot or full power down. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006

Comment: but I can't get into windows!

Comment: and `fwsetup` doesn't work and I'm sure that fast boot is off

Comment: and I can't remove the battery of the surface

Comment: Some tablets then have a tiny pin hole master reset. It may reset everything or just do a full reboot. Check settings if you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I found a way to get to the UEFI settings by holding the volumebutton at the top of the surface and pressing the boot button. I'm so glad that I didn't destroy the surface.