# Cannot access BIOS in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS since kernel update

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, grub-efi

Very recently my BIOS option is not accessible during the boot.

I checked the solution of [Adriaan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275998/943483) here but I'm puzzled.

```
(base) user@machine:~$ grep -e "^menuentry " /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-####' {
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

Well, it seems there is a `UEFI Firmware Settings` but seeing there are two menu entries, starting from which should I count ?

If it can help you to find a solution in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file the first menuentry is in `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###` part and the second menuentry is in `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###`.

```
#/boot/grub/grub.cfg file
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
        fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
```

`/etc/default/grub` is set as the following.

```
#/etc/default/grub file 
#If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Besides, looking at some boots log I suspect it's from Kernel Version update. I noticed the BIOS was not displayed those last days. Concretely in Tue Jun 8 my machine booted on 5.4.0-73-generic and since it has booted on 5.4.0-74-generic. If this is from this I am not experienced at all to do anything with this information unfortunately.

Motherboard (recognized by the OS) TUF Z390-PRO GAMING.
Version 
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-74-generic(x86_64)
Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 
Version: #83~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 11 16:01:00 UTC 2021

Answer (score 0):

#### Counting `menuentry`s

---

Count only the highest-level instances of `menuentry` and `submenu` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` — ignore anything within a `submenu`. If you have only Ubuntu installed, the UEFI Firmware Setup option should be third, after the `submenu` for advanced options — i.e., you would set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` since GRUB counts from `0`. If you’re dual-booting with Windows, the `GRUB_DEFAULT` should most likely be set to `3`.

#### Viewing the Menu

---

I notice that `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` is set to `countdown`. From [GRUB’s manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration), this means your GRUB menu would be **hidden** for `GRUB_TIMEOUT` (5 seconds in your case), but with only a **single number** (usually at the top-left) showing the countdown.

> In the ‘countdown’ case, it will show a one-line indication of the remaining time.

You probably want to set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to `"menu"`.

Even if you don’t, you *should* be able to view the menu during the 5-second countdown by pressing either `ESC`, `F4`, or holding `SHIFT`:

> If ESC or F4 are pressed, or SHIFT is held down during that time, it will display the menu and wait for input.

#### Getting to Firmware Setup

---

If your goal is to just *have the UEFI Firmware Setup* option show up, don’t change `GRUB_DEFAULT`, because you’ll enter setup each time you boot, then. Instead, try what I said above in *Viewing the Menu*.

---

**N.B.:** Remember to run `sudo update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grub`.

By the way, there is one possible cause of the UEFI entry disappearing from GRUB that I have here ignored; your machine may be booting up in Legacy BIOS mode, instead of UEFI. However if `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` really does contain a menu entry for `'System setup'` like you say it does, with the command `fwsetup` within it, then this is definitely not the case.

---

Note: the line that says `'System setup'` indicates that your *UEFI Firmware Setup* option in the GRUB menu will instead be titled *System setup*. Just a heads-up. You can name this anything you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is well introduced and clear, thank you. As you told my goal is having UEFI Firmware Setup option to show up. So I did not change `GRUB_DEFAULT` but `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to `menu`. The issue is my screen is totally black and displays nothing during the boot, it only shows the part where you select the user for a session.

Comment: Besides, when I press `Esc` and `F4` (one after one in order to wait for something displayed) I noticed something happens. I mean, the part to select the user for a session does not show up at all, it takes a lot more time, so I think there is something displayed but my screen keep black at this moment (but not black like 'No signal' you know).

Comment: Ah! The plot thickens! Interestingly, the issue you’re facing seems to really be the same as what I’ve experienced before, and those outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142167/grub-menu-working-but-hidden-cant-make-it-visible/1154020#1154020) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241577/grub-menu-not-visible). Just so we know for sure if it’s what I’ve seen before, could you try rebooting into UEFI-setup (using `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`), and then manually loading GRUB from there? (It’ll probably show up as `ubuntu` in the list)

Comment: This mayn’t do anything, but I have a hunch that most UEFI firmwares present different graphics capabilities, probably through changes in NVRAM variables, to the EFI image; depending on how you get to said image. On a 2019 MBP, as well as an old Dell Inspiron, e.g., GRUB is invisible (but fully functional) when accessed through iBoot and Dell’s UEFI respectively; it works fine when booted by default, though.

Comment: thank you anyway. Now, since I tried to unistall last kernel update as shown in the documentation, neither the bios UEFI shows up, nor the OS shows up. I reached I new level of troubles by my own... But I am pretty sure this all related to the last kernel update I did. Maybe my motherboard is over now, I don't know. I will test other hypothesis tomorrow morning.