# Is it possible to repair OS Ubuntu through a flash session AND from another device?

Tags: boot, kernel, usb-drive, boot-repair

Well, my BIOS UEFI stopped to show up during the boot these last days, I tried the solution of [MarbleMuffin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345698/cannot-access-bios-in-ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-since-kernel-update/1345702?noredirect=1#comment2299761_1345702) unfortunately it didn't work.
Actually, the BIOS option didn't show up but the OS Ubuntu did.

Because this change clearly seems to be related to a kernel update, I uninstalled the last kernel as presented in documentation through Synaptics program. The issue now is neither the BIOS, nor the OS show up. But I have a laptop (windows 7 based) where I did launch a flash session of Ubuntu and I can access the PC's hard drive (the root and the home user) connected by a docking. So that's why I wondered if it is possible to repair the OS Ubuntu system of my PC's hard drive through an Ubuntu flash session on my laptop, because I can access all the files.

I don't know if this is crucial but when I ask the laptop to boot on the PC's hard drive peripheral, there is only a white underscore "_" showing up for ever. I don't know if it means the OS system is clearly dead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Yes (you can fix issues from a *live* system), but the greater problem is working out what the issue is, thus what fix to apply.

Comment: @user68186 no because my issue is a lot worse. On the PC the screen keeps black as if there are no signal, and not any flash drive manages to "turn on". All the solutions presented are in the device itself, where this is disabled in my case. I am asking for flash session through another device!

Comment: @guiverc as I told to a previous one, reparing by the device itself through flash, I know how to do it, that's not the problem. I am asking if I can do through flash session from another device acting on the PC's hard drive.

Comment: You can boot a *live* system (that you seem to be referring to as *flash*), then `chroot` across to the actual system (ie. drive that contains the system you want to fix, it just wasn't used to boot) to correct issues...  For parts of the system that are damaged, you rely on the *live* system until it's fixed, then you reboot & test on the real system.  You're devoid of any specifics, so we're speaking generally - but yes it's possible.

Comment: @guiverc wow this is very interesting. I didn't find any mention about `chroot` until you did. And after I consulted the documentation it seems to be a very important tool to consider. Thank you.