# Stuck in motherboard logo screen forever, can't access UEFI or Grub2

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

I just updated some packages that was push to me by Update. After updating, I was asked to restart my system. Thereafter, on reboot I am stuck in the motherboard logo screen. Pressing F2 or Del to enter the UEFI does not work. It did not even proceed to the Grub2 menu or the show Ubuntu Logo screen. It just stayed in the motherboard logo screen forever...Ubuntu 18.04.

How do I fix such an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried rebooting the system on a few attempts each time giving it time to start up but to no avail.

This other method worked. I unplugged the power supply and waited for around half an hour before reconnecting the power supply cable to the system and powering it up. The system came back. Hope this info can be helpful to others facing this same situation.

Comment: Cold boot to get into UEFI or BIOS, remove battery or fwsetup, & force full system reconfig for hardware changes
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8  Re-Boot or warm boot, will not have UEFI/BIOS update any changes to hardware or configuration if UEFI "fast boot" is on.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks. I was initially planning to replace the mb battery hence unplugged the system power supply. While waiting for the battery replacement, and w/o removing the battery, I reconnected the power suppy and was able to boot up the system to my pleasant surprise. Hence sharing my discovery. No idea why my system could not boot...