# Cant access my bios (keyboard wont function/ turn on) Ubuntu 21.10/.04

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios, 21.10

So I got Linux about 3-4 months ago after making a custom computer. I was completely able to access it before hand after I turns some things off in bios, but I cant seem to access it at all anymore. what happens is my keyboard just shuts down and isn't powered it seems. what i think the issue is, is the numlock key because it isn't activated. and yes I know this chat isn't meant for this site but if you can help then thanks.

Comment: Please review the documentation for your motherboard. Accessing your BIOS menu doesn't involve Ubuntu and there's nothing in Ubuntu you can do about it. The BIOS menu is your motherboard firmware and it loads before any operating system.

Comment: Have you tried a full "cold" boot? And then turned off UEFI fast boot? Unable to access BIOS menu after installing Windows 8
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006