# Ubuntu dual boot setup unable to launch into bios or boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi

I have a Dell computer running a Ubuntu 22.04/Windows 10 dual boot setup. It was working pretty well, but recently I've no longer been able to enter the boot menu to select which OS to boot or enter the BIOS, even when I press the appropriate keys. When I do press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, the keys do something, because my computer will hang forever at a black screen leaving me only one option to shutdown and repower. My computer can boot normally if I press no keys.

I tried changing the GRUB-TIMEOUT-STYLE to the menu, but this did not bring me to a menu either.

I used `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` to reboot my system forcibly into the BIOS, but this only crashed and failed to boot properly. I get an error that says "software reset failed -524 and UBSAN array-index-out-of-bounds in a virtual box directory". I don't use a virtual box to boot Ubuntu, it's booting from hardware, I'm using the virtual box for something else. I attached the image of my error.

[image: image of the error]

Any suggestions about what to do? I'd be happy to reinstall I guess, though I would prefer not to lose any of my files/waste time unnecessarily. I uninstall and reinstalled virtual box, to no effect.

Also appreciated would be any theories about what I did wrong to my machine to cause this behavior so I can avoid it next time.

Comment: What model Dell? Often UEFI fast boot is so quick you do not have time to press key. If you can get into UEFI settings with "cold" boot or full power down & then press f2 just after Dell logo screen, but before anything else. UEFI update may have set system back to defaults & you have to redo some settings in UEFI. Both Windows and Ubuntu can do an UEFI update. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 Laptop full power reset. post #4 hold power on switch after removing battery
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12401315

Comment: It's a inspiron 3670. I read about fast boot as well, and I'm not sure if i turned that on or not, but I don't think it's on. It seems like I have plenty of time to press f2. It's not a laptop. I never see any dell logo anymore, it just goes straight to ubuntu for some reason. I think i used to see a dell logo but recently it has disappeared on startup. I will try again with cold boot.