Unable to Access BIOS on Lenovo P3 Tower Despite Multiple Attempts (BIOS Accessible at Repair Center)
I'm facing a frustrating issue with my Lenovo P3 Tower, and I'm hoping someone here can help.
System Details:
Model: Lenovo P3 Tower
GPU: NVIDIA T400 4 GB
Current OS: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)

The Issue:
I recently got my computer back from a repair center, and they informed me that the drivers were installed correctly. However, I'm now trying to access the BIOS to make some changes, but I can't seem to enter it, no matter how many times I try.
What I've Tried:
Pressing the usual keys (F2, F12, Esc, Del, etc.) repeatedly during startup—I've tried this over 100 times with no success.
Using a different keyboard and switching USB ports.
Attempting to access the BIOS from within Ubuntu using sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup.
Disabling Fast Boot and Secure Boot (if they were enabled) via Ubuntu.
The repair center sent me a picture showing that they were able to access the BIOS, so I know it's possible, but I just can't seem to get it to work on my end.

What I Need Help With:
Why might I be unable to access the BIOS even though the repair center could?
Are there any specific tricks or less common methods I can try to enter the BIOS on a Lenovo P3 Tower?
Could this be related to the installed drivers or any other software issue?
Is there a way to reset or force entry into the BIOS using hardware (e.g., a specific jumper or button on the motherboard)?

I’m trying to upgrade (or rather, downgrade) my OS from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for stability reasons, but I can't do that without accessing the BIOS to boot from a USB drive.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Maybe you could take your computer back to the repair centre and ask?  That would be more efficient.  Since BIOS starts first and then Ubuntu, I can't see how this would be related to Ubuntu.  If you took your hard drive (and, thus, Ubuntu) out, you should still be able to enter BIOS.  You shouldn't guess which key to hit; your motherboard or computer's manual should say it clearly.  The only reason I could see why you can't enter (based on what you've described) is that the key on your keyboard is broken...the keypress isn't being registered.  But I don't think this is Ubuntu related.

Booting live external media shouldn't require you to enter BIOS, unless a firmware/BIOS setting has it disabled. The next option I'd use is modifying your Ubuntu 22.10 grub so that an ISO you want to install is offered as a boot option; however you may need to install it elsewhere (or a different partition), and as Ubuntu 22.10 is EOL, we can't provide support there directly.  Ubuntu 22.10 would release-upgrade to 23.04 or the next release; however that release is EOL & the upgrade path is now gone.

FYI:  I suspect the drivers from your repair shop was bs; after being a EOL release there are have been no kernel modules (drivers) available for that release in years, and thus no drivers helpful actually exist that are useful today.  Your easiest option is to get your device to boot install media (this is device specific; so it's a hardware question though your firmware/BIOS plays a part, but the OS itself is not involved)

Watch the screen as you power up. BIOSes are manufacturer specific, but all the ones I have seen put a hint on the screen.

https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/p3_tw_linux_ug.pdf according to this it is F1 or FN+F1

You did a "cold" boot at repair shop or full power down. If UEFI fast boot is on, which it can be, but when making changes should not be on. The fast boot setting assumes no changes & UEFI does not scan system & write info for operating system to drive. Cold boot forces scan and just enough time to press a key. https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006 Also from Ubuntu. sudo systemctl reboot --firmware or
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup

Ubuntu 22.10 went EOL in July 20, 2023 and is off topic on this site. Sorry.

This question is similar to: No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I had the same issue. After trying all that you mentioned and different settings, still it did not work.
What worked for me in the end, was to connect the monitor to the DP port that is on the Nvidia graphics card, rather than the DP ports on the top. After this change, I was able to see the Lenovo logo upon start, and then press F1 to get into the BIOS settings.
